# Unable to update or locate packages after installing Ubuntu WSL on Windows 10

Tags: updates, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Windows Defender is not active. I have tried temporarily switching off Symantec antivirus. I can ping Google.

I was previously running Xubuntu in VirtualBox and it worked fine for a week and then kept freezing up. A switch to Ubuntu WSL was recommended. I'm not sure if this is related or not.

Comment: Show us complete output of `sudo apt update` from whatever Ubuntu system you are using.

Comment: Thank you @user535733

`Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done`

Comment: `All packages are up to date.
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-backports/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/InRelease`

Comment: `Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.`

Comment: Um, next time please put those in the question above. You can [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1223245/edit). Comments are transitory.

Comment: Looks like you have a DNS problem. What is the complete output of `ping -c3 8.8.8.8`? And of `ping -c3 www.google.com`?

Comment: Thank you @user535733. The problem resolved itself with a Windows upgrade from 1709 to 1909.

Answer (score 0):

The problem resolved itself with a Windows upgrade from 1709 to 1909. Windows Subsystem for Linux version 2 which features a true Linux kernel can also be upgraded from Windows Subsystem for Linux version 1 in Windows 10 version 2004 and later.